# data dependencies in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, decode, pipeline, microprocessors

Suppose in a 5 stage pipeline if the instructions dependent on others are made to wait in Decode Stage so, can we ignore WAR/WAW dependency checks for Instructions that are stuck in Decode Stage and pass them to next stage(EX) ? Will it be possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by stuck? Decoded or not yet?

Comment: Pipeline Stall since the operands are not available @AlexeyFrunze

Comment: [Operand forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand_forwarding) might help.

Comment: So forwarding the result of first instruction right after it completes execution and passing it to second instruction for it to use ?

Comment: Yes, if the result is available early enough. Specifically, the result at the end of the execution stage of one instruction can be fed into the execution stage of the following instruction, without having to wait for the result to be first written to the destination register in the later write stage.